# How can I use a Javascript library in Kotlin/JS?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js

I'm current learning how to use KotlinJS for web design and I can't figure out how to use a library like AnimeJS in my projects.

Please advise me on how I can do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is some advice on how to do this in the [Kotlin documentation here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/using-packages-from-npm.html):

To summarize, inside your `build.gradle` you can do:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation(npm("is-sorted"))
}
```

You will also need to declare the types for the library (e.g., inside `is-sorted.kt`)

```
@JsModule("is-sorted")
@JsNonModule
external fun <T> sorted(a: Array<T>): Boolean
```

Apart from the docs referenced above, [these slides](https://speakerdeck.com/erikhellman/building-progressive-web-apps-in-kotlin?slide=56) have a good explanation.